# How to customize xamarin forms UWP top bar

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to do a toolbar as this image (app topbar):

[image]

I want to add buttons cancel & save as it's shown in the image above. I am trying to do it with ToolbarItems, but I get [...] button, which actually acts as "dropdown".

[image]

Is there any way to make it as first image? Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/navigation-titleview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sermet mentioned , you could use NavigationPage.TitleView , the usage is pretty simple .

```
  <NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Text="Cancel" />
        <Label Text="Example Title" FontSize="Large" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Text="Save" Grid.Column="2"/>
    </Grid>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

[image]

#### Update

[image]

Comment: How can I make button take the full height of the titleview?

Comment: The grid(yellow area) does not occupy the whole space of title View , i tried set VerticalOptions to FillAndExpand , but no luck .